# How to loop through a object array in an Alexa Intent?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

So the problem is I am not able to loop through the question's array in the loop in the quizIntent handler. Only the first question is shown and then it does not move any further. Rest of the code is working fine.
What I want to do is **Keep on asking questions till the array runs out of them and break out of the loop when the user gives a wrong answer.**

I am just a newbie to Alexa Programming. Please help.

Here is my array

```
    const got = [
    {
        question: "Grey Wind, Lady, Ghost, Shaggydog, Summer and the sixth direwolve's name is?",
        answer: 'nymeria',
    },
    {
        question: "What was the name of the sinister castle where Arya and Gendry were held prisoner in season two?",
        answer: 'harrenhal',
    },
    {
        question: "What is a person called that can enter the minds of animals?",
        answer: 'warg',
    },
    {
        question: "What was the name of the Stark ancestral sword that was melted down by Tywin Lannister?",
        answer: 'ice',
    }
];
```

Here is my Alexa Intent

```
    var handlers = {
  "customIntent": function () {
           this.response.speak("Would you like to appear for a trial by combat");
      this.emit(":responseReady");
   },
   "quizIntent": function () {
       var mydecision = this.event.request.intent.slots.decision.value;
       if(mydecision=='no'||mydecision=='nope'||mydecision=='naah'){
        this.response.speak("A five year old has more courage than you.");
        this.emit(":responseReady");
       }

       for(var i = 0; i <got.length; i++){
            var myanswer = this.event.request.intent.slots.answer.value;
            var item = got[i].question;
            this.response.speak(item).listen();
            if(myanswer!=got[i].answer){
                this.response.speak("Wrong Answer. You are dead");
                this.emit(':responseReady');

            }
            if(i==got.length-1){
                this.response.speak("You won");
                this.emit(':responseReady');
            }

      }


   },
   "LaunchRequest": function () {
    this.response.speak("Valar Morghulis").listen("You are supposed to say Valar Dohareis"); 
    this.emit(":responseReady");
   }

};
```

Here is my Intent Schema in case you wanna look at that too

```
{
  "languageModel": {
    "types": [
      {
        "name": "answerSlot",
        "values": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Nymeria",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Harrenhal",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Warg",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Ice",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "decisionSlot",
        "values": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Yes",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "No",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Naah",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Yeah",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Yup",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "name": {
              "value": "Nope",
              "synonyms": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "intents": [
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "customIntent",
        "samples": [
          "Valar Dohareis",
          "hello",
          "hola"
        ],
        "slots": []
      },
      {
        "name": "quizIntent",
        "samples": [
          "{decision}",
          "The answer is {answer}"
        ],
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "decision",
            "type": "decisionSlot"
          },
          {
            "name": "answer",
            "type": "answerSlot"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "invocationName": "quiz game"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this an AWS lambda skill?

Comment: Yes. The problem is with the lambda function

Comment: Try and increase the timeout of the Lambda Function. Since Speaking is an async call, perhaps your Lambda function is timing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I figured out to solve this issue was :

```
    var i = 0;
var handlers = {
  "customIntent": function () {
           this.response.speak("Would you like to take part in a trial by combat?").listen();
      this.emit(":responseReady");
   },
   "quizIntent": function () {
       var mydecision = this.event.request.intent.slots.decision.value;
       if(mydecision=='no'||mydecision=='nope'||mydecision=='naah'){
        this.response.speak("Battles have been won against harder odds! Even little Lyanna Mormont has more courage than you.");
        this.emit(":responseReady");
       }

       if(i<=got.length){
           var item = got[i].question;
           if(i == 0){
                this.response.speak("Be attentive; just like life, I won't repeat or give you a second chance. Here you go; " + item).listen();
                this.emit(":responseReady");
           }
           else {
           this.response.speak(item).listen();
           this.emit(":responseReady");
           }
        }
   },

    "answerIntent": function () {  
            var myanswer = this.event.request.intent.slots.answer.value;

            if(myanswer!=got[i].answer){
                this.response.speak("Wrong Answer. The correct answer is " + got[i].answer + ". You are dead.");
                this.emit(':responseReady');

            }
            i++;
            if(i==got.length){
                i=0;
                this.response.speak("You emerged the ultimate victor. The best in all of Planetos.");
                this.emit(':responseReady');
            }
            this.response.speak("You survived. Say ready, when you are, for the next combat!").listen();
            this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
```

The idea is to switch back and forth through the quiz intent and the answer intent.

Answer (score 1):

[for](/questions/tagged/for) loop doesn't serve any purpose as [intent](/questions/tagged/intent) is designed to give a single response on every single invocation. So though you're [for](/questions/tagged/for) loop would be running, it will not emit out the second response as execution after the listen method of the first iteration would be starting from the very start since it's a new invocation.

The purpose you want to attain can be successfully achieved by using **Session attribute**.

```
var iterations = 0; //defined globally

// Later on, for every iteration, you simply need to call 
// into the attributes property of the alexa object to change the value.

this.attributes['iterations'] = iterations + 1;
```